# Rendering a HTML view in Flutter

Tags: html, xml, flutter, dart

I am receiving a response from the api which is HTML, and I would like to know how I render this answer, if there is a library or something.

I am very grateful, I am wanting to learn and I am having difficulties in some things.

The response from api is something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/199
flutter: ║ 9/xhtml"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"><head id="j_idt3">
flutter: ║    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta http-equiv="C
flutter: ║ ontent-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" conte
flutter: ║ nt="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
flutter: ║     <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /><link type="text/css" rel="s
flutter: ║ tylesheet" href="/SiGCExterno-war/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-parad
flutter: ║ ise-blue" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/SiGCExterno-war/javax.faces.reso
flutter: ║ urce/fa/font-awesome.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=7.0hc" />
```

It keeps going for a time
here is all the response: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1k_PsbFx5_x9SXPIBzDRpXa8TnJYlANMFVxhoTibZZZ4/edit?usp=sharing

How can i render this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this package [simple_html_css](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_html_css)